# Load features created by custom primitives

Tags: featuretools

I created some features base on custom primitives with help of featuretools and saved them into memory. Then I want load them with `featuretools.load_features` function. But I get the error `RuntimeError: Primitive "LastTime" in module "__main__" not found`
where `LastTime` is my custom primitive name.

So my question is how to properly load my custom features or to let featuretools know that such primitives exist ?

I have searched over documentation and issues on GitHub and didn't find proper information about it

Answer (score 1):

Before loading in the saved features, re-run the code that defined the custom primitive.